# Unable to produce values of a kernel density estimator in R

Tags: r

I'm simulating random numbers from the exponential distribution with rate=1. I have plotted a kernel density of the data using the density() function in R. What I want is a function f that gives me the value of the density at any point. I have tried the following code:

```
n=10^5
x=rexp(n,rate=1)
d=density(x,kernel="gaussian")
f=function(x){d$y[x]}
f(1)
plot(d)
```

However,
f(1) clearly does not match the value of the density function at the point x=1. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`density` produces a list which contains, in field `x`, the coordinates of the points at which the density is evaluated and, in field `y`, the estimated values of the density at these coordinates:

```
> str(d)
List of 7
 $ x        : num [1:512] -0.348 -0.328 -0.307 -0.286 -0.266 ...
 $ y        : num [1:512] 0.00146 0.00256 0.00435 0.00717 0.01147 ...
......
```

To get a function from `x` and `y`, you can use the `approxfun` function:

```
> f <- approxfun(d$x, d$y)
> f(1)
[1] 0.3665273
> dexp(1, rate=1)
[1] 0.3678794
```

In your code you get `d$y[1]`, which is the first value of `d$y`.